# Add constraint unique column with null value

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, unique

I need to create a constraint of integrity that ensures that in a column of a table there is only one null valor. The classic UNIQUE is not good because it does not detect multiple nulls ...
how can I do?

Comment: Does any business logic or interface prevent you from using a unique 'no data' value instead of a null?

Comment: The problem is that it is a constraint of an exam exercise so I can not make design choices

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE qwe(
  id int
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX qwe_idx ON qwe( 
      CASE WHEN id IS null THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(id) END 
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO qwe VALUES(1);
1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO qwe VALUES(1);
Error starting at line : 9 in command -
INSERT INTO qwe VALUES(1)
Error report -
ORA-00001: naruszono więzy unikatowe (TEST.QWE_IDX)
```

---

```
INSERT INTO qwe VALUES(NULL);
1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO qwe VALUES(NULL);
Error starting at line : 9 in command -
INSERT INTO qwe VALUES(NULL)
Error report -
ORA-00001: naruszono więzy unikatowe (TEST.QWE_IDX)
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM qwe;

        ID
----------
         1
    (null)
```

Comment: This will work on a column like ID, which is of NUMBER data type. If the column is a VARCHAR2 column, comparing to the string 'NULL' may not work, since that may be a valid value in the column. However, a small modification will work - for example create a unique constraint on concatenating a space at the end of the column value. (This shouldn't work if Oracle treated NULL according to the standard, but it doesn't.)

Comment: @mathguy for string (varchar2) columns solutions is also very easy, just:`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on table( CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 1 END )`

Comment: That solution is incorrect: the 1 will be cast to VARCHAR2 and it may collide with a valid value in the column (the string '1'). I already described one correct solution (which does not rely on advance knowledge of valid and invalid values in the column) in my comment.

Comment: Also, you probably meant `when column is null then 1 ELSE COLUMN end`.

Comment: @mathguy - no. Just create ordinary unique constraint on this (string) column and, **in addition**, create this second unique, functional index that prevents from inserting two nulls.

Comment: Oh, got it. You are right, that will work just fine, and probably more efficiently than what I suggested.